# display all fields from sqlite table to json without naming each field

Tags: json, sqlite

i want smth like

```
SELECT
    json_object(
    all
    )

from ref_quest_state
```

is it possible? I've tried

```
json_object(*),
json_object(),
json_object(all)
```

and it doesn't work

---

for example

```
CREATE TABLE ref_quest_state (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
   name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

and i want to display result as json, but i donn't want to write smth like

```
 SELECT
    json_object(
    'id', id, 
    'name', name
    )

from ref_quest_state
```

to get result as

> {"id":1,"name":"in progress"} {"id":2,"name":"failed"}
> {"id":3,"name":"succeed"}

Comment: Could you add more details ? some simple data and the expected can help a lot